# how to connect two connection strings and insert data from one database into another MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, gridview

Currently trying to add data from one database to another, using ASP.Net into the Database from a

The database that i am using are both MySQL - can connect to each one with no problems - just not working together to push data both together...?  Code below is what I have been trying to get working...

```
string connStringOne = "User ID=*****;Password=*****;Host=*****;Port=3306;Database=databaseOne;";
string connStringTwo = "User ID=*****;Password=*****;Host=*****;Port=3306;Database=databaseTwo;";

// First Connection
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connStringOne);
string myGetQuery = "SELECT * FROM databaseOne.tbl_user WHERE User_ID=55";
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(myGetQuery);
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myConnection.Open();

// Second Connection
MySqlConnection myConnectionTwo = new MySqlConnection(connStringTwo);
string myInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO databaseTwo.tbl_users (User_ID) ";
MySqlCommand myCommandTwo = new MySqlCommand(myInsertQuery);
myCommandTwo.Connection = myConnectionTwo;
myConnectionTwo.Open();


// Stuck here.
```

Add to Datagrid or into the Database...?
    //   myCommand.
    //   myCommandTwo.

```
myCommand.Connection.Close();
myCommandTwo.Connection.Close();
```

So getting information for User (55) and adding that details into another Database - getting the persons address etc...  Have mapped the two databases the same

```
databaseTwo.tbl_users
ID (Primary Key) (Auto Numbers..)
User_ID
CustomerName
CustomerPoints

databaseOne.tbl_user
ID (Primary Key) (Auto Numbers..)
User_ID
CustomerName
CustomerPoints
```

Any help would be great or pointing me in the right direction etc... where I can figure it out...

Thanks in advance - simon

Comment: just a quick suggestion, have you tried stepping through your code? if it works that way, then you might want to include a thread.Sleep between the two commands (also, this question is fine right up until you ask for a tutorial - remove that since asking is off topic for SO)

Comment: Your SQL `INSERT` statement looks rather short. Perhaps some additional columns, and values for them, would help.

Comment: Hi jbutler483, Have removed the tutorial wording in main Question.. - thanks for the update on SO...  Just new to SO, just bear with... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After you open first connection, get what you want to get into a DataTable, array, whatever.
2. Close the connection and open the second one.
3. Push what you want to push from that data you got from first db.

For third step, you can create an sql command dynamicly like this:

```
string sql="";
foreach(DataRow dr in yourdatatable.Rows){
   sql += "INSERT INTO table2 (column1) VALUES ('"+dr["something"]+"'); ";
}
//and here execute this sql
```

Comment: 3. Push what you want to push from that data you got from first db... How to do this..?   Have done 1 and 2 but stuck on 3... What I did the connection and got 2 * Search * SQL string into two gridviews - but stuck at merging them or saving to Local database eg Database One...       Have separate one as just merged as a DataTable - still stuck on how to export / insert/Update this result back into the databaseTwo . tbl_users...  Any help would be great - bashing my head against this... doh...

Comment: I added an example, you can modify it for your needs, delete, update whatever.